# brizy install extension-zip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I keep getting an error for brizy saying

"The following extensions are required for Brizy plugins properly work:
extension-zip"

the hyperlink just directs me to https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php, with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your host to enable or you can enable it from cPanel or console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).